# Passing cid as argument to backbone collection get function doesn't work in version 1.0.0

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have seen some posts regarding the same issue, however the replies there weren't enough or in the right direction as mine.
So i have a backbone collection, and when i want to get a particular model out of it, i wish to pass `cid` value to the `.get()` function. But by doing that i get `undefined` in response, however, if i pass in the `id` then it works fine.
Their doc says that both `cid` and `id` are acceptable as arguments. Any idea how to make this work?

Say i have a model with `id` as 5, and `cid` as 'abc'. When I write this : `this.collection.get(5);` I get the desired model, however when I write this : `this.collection.get('abc');` I get `undefined` in result.

Comment: Some code to illustrate your problem? And the version of Backbone you use?

Comment: version is mentioned in question. It's 1.0.0. I'm editing my question to include some code

Comment: Did you override the function to assign`cids? Or are you manually assigning them? Because by default backbone uses the letter "c" as a prefix for the `cid` (so you wouldn't end up with a `cid` of *"abc"*).

Comment: Oh wow! what a hint Jack! I was manually setting `cid` value as some other string for some reason. So if I use that string in `get()` function, it doesn't work. But if i don't change `cid` value at runtime, then this function works perfectly! For that matter, even if I make sure that the new string value that i assign to `cid` has prefix 'c', still it wasn't working. So is it that I am not supposed to change its value at all?

Comment: It might also depend on how you are assigning it, are you using the `set` function, or just assigning using myModel.cid = 'abs' (try it both ways). That said I think that the get function looks for a cid with a "c" prefix so it probably won't work unless you override it.

Comment: Good idea, but I just tried the `set()` function and it still doesn't work. Earlier I was simply assigning value.

Comment: Oh one more interesting observation, even if I set its value using `set()` function, it's true that I cant use that value in `get()` but the original value is still usable in `get()`! And I did see that cid's value got changed due to `set()` but still it is accessible only through its original value

Comment: I just did a quick test and you should be able to assign the `cid` manually, here's a basic [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkJCx/1/), can you show the code where your doing the assignment? Did you try inspecting the models in your collection (using whichever JavaScript debugger you use) to see if it actually has the `cid` you assigned?

Comment: I checked your jsfiddle and I noticed that you are first defining a model and it's cid attribute and then adding it to the collection, in which case it's perfectly fine. But in my case, i change cid of an existing model in the collection, that's why it doesn't work

Comment: Would removing and readding the model work for you? Also note that would have the same issue if you try and modify the `id` property (you can easily test that by modifying the jsfiddle).

Comment: Yeah well, I think I should just continue with the original cid values. But thanks a lot Jack, this information is really important to me :)